# How to get a token at a specified index from a parser rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In my custom editor i would like to correct errors which are detected from extra error parser rules.

For example i have this error rule in my parser:

```
|   'if' '(' expr ')' ')'  expr
```

which detects unnecessary parentheses.

I can get the start and the stop token in a listener and calculate the position.

But for my fix i need the extra parentheses token (at index 5) to calculate the position in my custom language editor which then makes it possible to delete the char.

What is the right way to get a token at a specified index according to the parser rules?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to *label* the extra `)` like this:

```
|   'if' '(' expr ')' extra=')'  expr
```

In your listener, you can then do the following to get the index of the `)`:

```
int index = ctx.extra.getStartIndex();
```

If the alternative with the `extra` label is not parsed, you might get a NPE, so when there are multiple alternatives, check if `ctx.extra` is not `null`.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed. Is there also an extra label necessary if i try to detect a missing parentheses, e.g.: |   'if' '(' expr  expr  or: |  '{'  exprlist   Something like the opposite, e.g. extra=' '?

Comment: No, you can't label a missing token.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast answer!